# Twitter Auth 1.0 for get api call C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I am using twitter api to fetching attachments from twitter direct messages. Below is my code for api calling for get method. But status of this api call is unauthorized. can any one help me out?

```
        int timestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
        string nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(timestamp.ToString()));
        string signingKey = consumerSecret + "&" + tokenSecret;
        string requestString = "https://ton.twitter.com/1.1/ton/data/dm/1461588240331333639/1461588226477633536/rb4t_19r.jpg";//TwitterConfiguration.EndpointUrl + OAuthRequestTokenRoute;

        string parameterString =
            //$"oauth_callback={WebUtility.UrlEncode("https://twitter.com/")}&" +
            //$"include_entities={WebUtility.UrlEncode("true")}&" +
            $"{WebUtility.UrlEncode("oauth_consumer_key")}={WebUtility.UrlEncode(consumerKey)}&" +
            // $"outh_consumer_secret={WebUtility.UrlEncode(consumerSecret)}&" +
            $"{WebUtility.UrlEncode("oauth_nonce")}={WebUtility.UrlEncode(nonce)}&" +
            $"{WebUtility.UrlEncode("oauth_signature_method")}={WebUtility.UrlEncode("HMAC-SHA1")}&" +
            $"{WebUtility.UrlEncode("oauth_timestamp")}={WebUtility.UrlEncode(timestamp.ToString())}&" +
            $"{WebUtility.UrlEncode("oath_token")}={WebUtility.UrlEncode(accessToken)}&" +
            // $"oath_token_secret={WebUtility.UrlEncode(tokenSecret)}" +
            $"{WebUtility.UrlEncode("oauth_version")}={WebUtility.UrlEncode("1.0")}";


        string signatureBaseString =
            "GET&" +
            WebUtility.UrlEncode(requestString) +
            "&" +
            WebUtility.UrlEncode(parameterString);
        byte[] signatureBaseStringBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signatureBaseString);
        byte[] signingKeyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signingKey);
        HMACSHA1 hmacSha1 = new HMACSHA1(signingKeyBytes);
        byte[] signature = hmacSha1.ComputeHash(signatureBaseStringBytes);
        string base64Signature = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
        var client = new RestClient($"https://ton.twitter.com/1.1/ton/data/dm/1461588240331333639/1461588226477633536/rb4t_19r.jpg?oauth_consumer_key={consumerKey}&oauth_token={accessToken}&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp={timestamp}&oauth_nonce={nonce}&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature={base64Signature}");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        //request.AddHeader("Cookie", "guest_id=v1%3A162788511360812405; guest_id_ads=v1%3A162788511360812405; guest_id_marketing=v1%3A162788511360812405; personalization_id=\"v1_iTPkDiU3AyzBuwhAON7Q0w==\"");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: have you followed this: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/direct-messages/message-attachments/guides/retrieving-media